# Create trigger for update of specific columns

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, triggers

I've created a trigger to update a column on any changes

This is not the real table, just an example

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    _id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    title TEXT,
    type TEXT,
    value TEXT,
    updated_on INTEGER
)

CREATE TRIGGER updated_on
    AFTER UPDATE ON tablename BEGIN
    UPDATE tablename SET updated_on=strftime('%s', datetime('now', 'localtime'), 'utc')
          WHERE _id=NEW._ID;
    END;
```

I need the trigger to avoid update if only a specific column was updated.
In the specific example case, I need to only call the trigger if `title` or `type` was updated, but do not call the trigger if ONLY `value` was updated.

I tried like

```
CREATE TRIGGER updated_on
    AFTER UPDATE OF 'title','type' ON tablename BEGIN
            UPDATE tablename SET updated_on=strftime('%s', datetime('now', 'localtime'),'utc')
                WHERE _id=NEW._ID;
    END;
```

but the trigger doesn't update at all.

Comment: This trigger works for me.

Comment: @CL thanks. If it weren't for your comment I wouldn't have thought that the error was not in the syntax. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trigger I created in the question is the correct implementation.

The error was in a real project because I misspelled the real column names in first place.